# Converting a dictionary into numbering format

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

I have the following multi-dictionaries which are inputs to the python script:

```
 { 123 {'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 1, 'longword': 5, '@': 1} }
 { 486 {'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 0, 'longword': 0, '@': 0} }
```

**I have to convert into numbering format i.e. 123 will be 1, 486 will be 2 and so on.**

**For 'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 1, 'stop_words': 10,'longword': 5, '@': 1** 
all_uppercase will be 1, stop_words will be 2, longword will be 3, @ will be 4.

So the final output that should be printed should look like this:

```
 { 1 {'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 5, '4': 1} }
 { 2 {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0} }
```

**Here is my code:**

```
 inner_dict = {}
 count =0
 def analyze_tweets():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        d = ast.literal_eval(line)
        for k,v in d.items():
           inner_dict = dicts.setdefault(k, {})
           for i in inner_dict.items()
```

Comment: your code seems unfinished.  what's your question?

Comment: yes how do I get the output as I need. { 1 {'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 5, '4': 1} }
 { 2 {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0} }

Comment: if you have a speific problem with your code then we'd be glad to help, but generally SO isn't for writing your code for you.  it looks like you just gave up halfway.

Comment: @Eevee I am new to dictionaries. I know how to loop in individual key or value but how do I associate a numbering, it just confuses me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary is,

```
 d = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}
```

then you must do this:

```
 dict((key,val) for key,val in enumerate(sorted(d))
```

This will associate numbers to your keys.