# Multi dictionary - convert keys of dictionary to numbers

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

I have the following multi-dictionary which get output from a file and in my script, its taken as standard input:

```
{ 345 : {'name': 5, 'count': 6, 'top': 0} }
{ 233 : {'name': 6, 'count': 4, 'top': 0} }
{ 123 : {'name': 2, 'count': 9, 'top': 1} }
```

I want to convert all the keys of the dictionary to numbers like this:

```
{ 1 : {'1': 5, '2': 6, '3': 0} }
{ 2 : {'1': 6, '2': 4, '3': 0} }
{ 3 : {'1': 2, '2': 9, '3': 1} }
```

Output of the file should be:

```
 1 1: 5 2: 6 3: 0
 2 1: 6 2: 4 3: 0
 3 1: 2 2: 9 3: 1
```

I am trying to understand dictionaries and new to python so wondering how I can achieve it. 

Here is my code

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    d = ast.literal_eval(line)
    for k,v in d.items():
       inner_dict = dicts.setdefault(k, {})
       inner_dict= dict((t,i) for (t,i) in enumerate(sorted(dicts.keys())))

for key, value in inner_dict.items():
   print key, value
```

The above code gives me the following output but does not give me what I want.

```
0 123
1 233
2 345
```

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Is it okay if the input is dict of dicts?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes this is exactly the input. { 345 : {'name': 5, 'count': 6, 'top': 0} }
{ 233 : {'name': 6, 'count': 4, 'top': 0} }
{ 123 : {'name': 2, 'count': 9, 'top': 1} }

Comment: But thats not dict of dicts.

Comment: @thefourtheye what do you mean by dicts of dicts then? it is a dictionary within a dictionary

Comment: `{ 345 : {'name': 5, 'count': 6, 'top': 0},
  233 : {'name': 6, 'count': 4, 'top': 0},
  123 : {'name': 2, 'count': 9, 'top': 1}}` is a dict of dicts

Comment: In your code, you are enumerating the sorted keys but in your *like this* example the enumeration isn't per the sorted keys.  Which do you want?

Comment: @thefourtheye So the answer to your question is No, its not okay if the input is dict of dicts as my input should be the same as I showed above i.e. dictionary printed line by line.. Its a dictionary within a dictionary i.e. { 345 : {'name': 5, 'count': 6, 'top': 0} } where 345 is key to values {'name': 5, 'count': 6, 'top': 0} and again name, count, top are keys in values of 345.

Comment: @wwii I corrected that sorting. It prints like above. I dont care about sorting at all.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.  Once you make one, in this case using `ast.literal_eval`, there's no way to get the order `name`, `count`, `top` back unless you tell it explicitly.  Try `print({"name": 1, "count": 2, "top": 3})` at the console, for example.

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779346/converting-a-dictionary-into-numbering-format
which was asked yesterday and actually answered by yourself??

Comment: Yes it is but it might have solved the problem for him but in my case, its a different problem as I want to replace the keys whereas he wanted to associate numbers.

Comment: @DSM It is fine if the order is incorrect like I dont care if count has 1 and top has 2 and name has 3 as long as it numbers and replaces.

Comment: the input and output you both want seems almost exactly the same though?

Comment: Does not solve my problem like I might have solved his.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Produce *dictionaries* as specified in the example:

```
# generate individual converted dictionaries 
# not tested with sys.stdin
def gen_with_appropriate_name():
    for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, 1):
        d = ast.literal_eval(line)
        sub_d = d.values()[0]
        yield {n : {'1' : sub_d['name'],
                     '2' : sub_d['count'],
                     '3' : sub_d['top']}}
```

#### The following will produce a similar result with the enumeration of the *sub dictionary* based on its original keys, sorted.

```
# generate individual converted dictionaries 
# not tested with sys.stdin
def gen_with_appropriate_name():
    for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, 1):
        d = ast.literal_eval(line)
        items = d.values()[0].items()
        items.sort(key = lambda itm: itm[0])
        yield {n: {i+1:item[1] for i, item in enumerate(items)}}
```

#### Usage -with printout in format specified

```
d = gen_with_appropriate_name()
for thing in d:
    first =  str(thing.keys()[0])
    second =  thing.values()[0]
    print first + ' ' + ' '.join('{}: {}'.format(*item) for item in second.iteritems())
```

#### Output using the first function:

```
1 1: 5 3: 0 2: 6
2 1: 6 3: 0 2: 4
3 1: 2 3: 1 2: 9
```

#### Output using second function

```
1 1: 6 2: 5 3: 0
2 1: 4 2: 6 3: 0
3 1: 9 2: 2 3: 1
```

#### Explanation:

```
gen_with appropriate_name()
```

This function gets data from sys.stdin one *line* at a time and generates a dictionary for each of those lines *in turn*.  It is iterable.  http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-iterable

```
yield {n: {i+1:item[1] for i, item in enumerate(items)}}
```

The yield statement makes the function a generator. The function is suspended at the yield statement until next() is called, then execution resumes til another yield statement is encountered. A generator's next() method returns the value of the yield statement's expression list.
http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr

```
{n: {i+1:item[1] for i, item in enumerate(items)}}
```

This is the yield statement's expression list.  It creates a dictionary with n as the key. The value is a dictionary created with a *dictionary display* which is similar to a list comprehension.
http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dic‌​tionaries

Comment: This might solve my problem but I have 40,000 lines of dictionary and putting all of them in a list does not seem efficient. Is there a way to interpret as a dictionary itself and do the sorting instead of putting in a list.

Comment: Yep, use generators.  See the edit.  I'll risk a downvote for the un-tested *edit-on-the-fly*

Comment: Works perfect although does not considers last line and stops n-1. Thank you so much. What does this line do: 
yield {n: {i+1:item[1] for i, item in enumerate(items)}}

Comment: I've never worked with sys.stdin, so I'm not sure why the *last* item wouldn't be processed - the for statement is calling the next method of sys.stdin, maybe it is expecting a newline charater?.  Perhaps some else could jump in.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok If I wanted to print  without curly brace then  how would I do it. 
1 1: 6 2: 5 3: 0 
2 1: 4 2: 6 3: 0

Comment: Use format strings.  http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: Is there a way to do it here itself, {n: {i+1:item[1] for i, item in enumerate(items)}} as we are choosing to print that way.

Comment: Yes, the function can generate formatted strings.  Create a fromatted string and use it for the yield expression.

Comment: I am confused how as m new to python. @wwii

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me exactly what you want to do.  The generator will *produce* individual dictionaries.  You can process those as you see fit.  What is the final output of your problem? Do you only wish to print the *data* in the format you just specified or are you going to do anything else with it?

Comment: Note that rather than using `n+1` in your dict comprehension, you can tell `enumerate` to start counting from 1: `for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, 1):`

Comment: @Blckknght Excellent, thank you for that.  Must be time to review the docs again.